# Saving video frames with timestamps

Tags: python, opencv

I needed to save the image frame with the file name as the Timestamp. I tried to add timestamp by `time.time()` function in `cv2.putText()` function and It just writes `time.time()` .

Also I tried using `time.time()` in place of image name of `cv2.imwrite()` function and its not adding timestamp either.

```
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cv2.putText(frame,'time.time()',(10,500), font, 4,(255,255,255),2,cv2.CV_AA). 

                           
cv2.imwrite('str(time.time())'+str(i)+'.jpg',frame)
`
The issue is resolved by putting str(time.time()).
```

Comment: Don't use `'time.time()'` use `str(time.time())`. You put it in quotes and thus made `time.time()` a literal string instead of using its output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have `time.time()` in quotes so it literally sets the text as a string called "time.time()". To display the actual value of `time.time()`, remove the quotations. From the docs, [`cv2.putText()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#puttext) takes in a `str` for the 2nd parameter. Here's the definition

```
cv2.putText(img, text, org, fontFace, fontScale, color[, thickness[, lineType[, bottomLeftOrigin]]])
```

So in your case, you can just turn the value of `time.time()` into a `str` type like this

```
cv2.putText(frame, str(time.time()), (10,500), font, 4, (255,255,255), 2, cv2.CV_AA)
```

Similarly with `cv2.imwrite()`, instead of the literal string, you can turn the value into a `str` type to get the timestamp

```
cv2.imwrite(str(time.time()) + '_' + str(i) + '.jpg', frame)
```